# How to determinate that Fragment is root in the back stack in onCreateView?

Tags: android, android-fragments

Now, I try to get a back stack size in my `Fragment` in `onCreateView` method. But it returns an old back stack size. So, I get:

- Open first fragment -> back stack size 0
- Open second fragment -> stack size 0 (I need 1)
- Third fragment -> stack size 1 (I need 2)

How can I get back stack size including new adding fragment? 

P.S. My problem that I launch all same fragments (profile page) just it has different tags and arguments. So, I don't know how to determinate a real back stack size when I create view for a new fragment to show navigation up or drawer icon.

Method to open new fragment:

```
protected void startFragment(final String tag, Fragment fragment, @Nullable Bundle arguments) {

    if (arguments != null) {
        fragment.setArguments(arguments);
    }

    getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager()
        .beginTransaction()
        .add(R.id.container, fragment, tag)
        .addToBackStack(tag)
        .commit();
}
```

Comment: post your code for adding the fragments